# Unexpected token ? error while deploying Cartridge changes of SFCC using GIT

Tags: github, build, jestjs, devops, salesforce-commerce-cloud

we trying to deploy to instance
getting below error

/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/sfra-webpack-builder/node_modules/jest-worker/build/index.js:126
enableWorkerThreads: this._options.enableWorkerThreads ?? false,

Node-v14.21.3
npm -v7.0.11

ho to resolve this error